# Как считывать n-ю строку из файла?

Tags: c++, файлы

Имеется текстовый файл, состоящий из структур, в каждой по три строки
(1-я строка: название, 2-я: номер, 3-я: массив из 5 чисел).
Мне нужно каждую третью строку файла записывать в другой массив.

Как перемещаться по нужным позициям в файле?

Если бы я вручную вводил, то делал это так:

```
for (int k=0; k<5; k++)
cin >> m[k];
```

Или если бы нужно было записать только одну строку:

```
ifstream in("file.txt");
for (int k=0; k<5; k++)
in >> m[k];
```

Comment: @PiPiPARU, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 4):

Специально перемещаться по позициям не нужно. Просто читайте файл по строкам и подсчитывайте их номера. Каждую третью выводите.

```
string s;
int n = 0;

while (getline(in, s)) {
  if ((++n % 3) == 0)
    cout << s << '\n';
}
```